# Is there a way to dynamically update the file every minute without updating the extra content

Tags: linux, bash, shell, unix

Is there a way to dynamically update the file every minute without updating the content

Until implement the solution I need text file to be update every 1 minutes.
but content of the file need to be same , to update the file right now i'm doing open the file in vi editor then delete the ok text and again write same ok and save ,
Is it possible to do this task using bash script .

Example File content :

```
Jobname1 ok
Jobname2 ok
Jobname3 ok
Jobname4 Fail
Jobname5 ok
```

dynamically update the file every minute without updating the content to feed the file to program .
program detecting the only updated file only.

Comment: `while sleep 60; do sed 's/ok//g' file.txt; done` ?

Comment: if the intention is to update the file's modification date/time stamp: `touch <filename>`

Comment: Am I correct in thinking that every minute you want to make a change to the file, save the change, undo the change, and save the file again (leaving the contents as they were before)?  If so, how long a delay should there be between the two saves (e.g. one second)?

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps you need just this

```
while sleep 60; do
    touch -am file.txt
done
```

#### edit

Add `-am` as it's not clear what attribute `program` is considering

Comment: It's not working touch the file program not identify the file , need activity do something

Comment: Specify what's `program` and how it's detecting the file changed

Comment: It's datadog monitoring , agent looking for update file only , if it's not updating content not shipping to datadog